# Not able to add reviewer in pull request

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm using Azure DevOps with `free Subscriptions` and currently when i tried to add `reviewers` in one of my project, it always fails with below error.

> Failed to create pull request: The reviewer user@gmail.com does not
> have permission to view this pull request

Already user `user@gmail.com` added under `Project settings > Permissions > Project Administrators` group.

Project administrators permission is not sufficient to deal with pull request?

Comment: This really isn't something that can be resolved here (it's not programming-related, more of an Azure DevOps config question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you assign a Basic license to the user? Every subscription has 5 Basic licenses for free. Follow the steps below if you have not done that yet:

1. Go to `https://dev.azure.com/orgname`
2. Click on **Organization Settings**
3. Go to **Users** and on the right hand, click **Add Users**
4. Select **Basic license**
5. Under **Projects**, choose your project and give the user **Project Administrator** permission.

Comment: Tight bananas brother thanks.